# MVC routing troubles

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-mvc-routing

Really having trouble getting to grips with MVC routing despite reading loads of blogs and tutorials on it...

I have this webapi function:

```
public HttpResponseMessage UpsertProducts([FromUri] int marketplaceId, [FromUri] int datasourceId, [FromBody]List<HeisenbergProduct> heisenbergProducts)
```

and the default route in `Route.config`:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "Default",
    url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
);
```

All worked fine.

I've now added another function:

```
public HttpResponseMessage ReviseInventory([FromUri] int marketplaceId, [FromUri] int datasourceId, [FromBody]List<HeisenbergReviseInventory> heisenbergReviseInventories)
```

Despite the action names being different, there seems to be a conflict and when calling either of them I get a `500 internal server error` - I guess it doesn't know which one to use.

I'm calling them using URL:

```
api/webapiproducts/upsertproducts?marketplaceId={0}&datasourceId={1}
```

I tried to get around the issue by using attribute routing:

```
[Route("/api/WebApiProducts/upsertproducts/{marketplaceid}/{datasourceid}")]
public HttpResponseMessage UpsertProducts([FromUri] int marketplaceId, [FromUri] int datasourceId, [FromBody]List<HeisenbergProduct> heisenbergProducts)
```

and

```
[Route("/api/WebApiProducts/reviseinventory/{marketplaceid}/{datasourceid}")]
public HttpResponseMessage ReviseInventory([FromUri] int marketplaceId, [FromUri] int datasourceId, [FromBody]List<HeisenbergReviseInventory> heisenbergReviseInventories)
```

Neither of my routing attributes seem to work. What am I doing wrong and what am I not understanding about routing here?

As @Nkosi pointed out I'd put the wrong route file! Here is my WebApiConfig.cs contents:

```
config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
    name: "DefaultApi",
    routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
    defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
);

config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
    name: "DefaultActionApi",
    routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
    defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Managed to get it working with attribute routing by changing the URL I'm calling to this:

```
string.Format("api/webapiproducts/reviseinventory/{0}/{1}", marketplaceId, datasourceId);
```

Answer (score 1):

The route config you showed is for MVC not web api. Look for the `WebApiConfig.cs` file which will have the route set up for Web API

```
public static class WebApiConfig
{
    public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        // Attribute routing.
        config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

        // Convention-based routing.
        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultActionApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );

        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
}
```

The default convention-based route setup usually looks like this

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
    name: "DefaultApi",
    routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
    defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
);
```

with out the action placeholder which is what would be causing your route conflicts.

to enable attribute routing do this

```
config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();
```

Update the `WebApiConfig` to include the proper setup should fix your problem for both convention-based and attribute routing.

Comment: you're correct - I added the wrong config file contect - I've updated the question to have the correct data. Still has issues using my query string parameters though. I've managed to get it working by changing the URL I'm calling - I thought you could do both ways. See my answer

Comment: @Rick. They can work both ways. The order of mapping routes is important as the first route matched wins with more specific routes being mapped first and more general routes mapped later down the line. you need to switch the order by putting the last mapping up by one. it is not reaching the second convention-based route because it is already being matched to the first one.

Comment: thanks, yes you're correct about the ordering - I forgot about it. I changed the order and tried to call using the querystring method but it still didn't work. I still seem to have to use the method I've put in my answer.